# Is this hardware configuration Ubuntu 10.04 compatible?

Tags: 10.04, hardware

I am ready to buy these components for my new linux workstation. I am a software developer and I would like to create a multimonitor workstation like this one

```
1 - KVR1333D3N9K2/8  Kingston Kit 2*4GB DDR3-1333 PC3-10666 Unbuffered
1 - ST500DM002       Seagate Barracuda 7200.12 500Gb 7200rpm 16Mb SataIII 3.5"
1 - BX80623I52500K   Intel Core i5 2500K 3.30GHz Cache 6MB Sandy Bridge LGA1155 BOX
1 - CAFA70           Corsair Cooling CAFA70 CPU Dual Cooler Intel sk1366/1156/775 AMD AM2/AM3
1 - RS700-AMBAD3-EU  Cooler Master SILENT PRO M700 700Watt EPS/ATX12V Modulare 20/24+4/8+6/8pin PFC Attivo 80+ Bronze
2 - ZT-50401-10L     Zotac NVIDIA GeForce GTX550 Ti 1GB Gddr5 192bit 2*Dvi/HDMI/DP PCi-Ex
1 - SABERTOOTH/P67   Asus SABERTOOTH P67 i7/i5/i3 SLI/CrossFire DDR3 GLan USB 3.0 sk1155 ATX
```

Edit:

I have bought these components:

- Hard Disk Interno Western Digital Caviar Green 500GB 3.5" Intellipower 32MB WD5000AADS
- Case Midi Cooler Master Centurion 5 II ATX Nero
- VGA Club 3d Radeon HD 6870 Core 900MHz Memory GDDR5 4200MHz 1GB 2xDVI HDMI 2xminiDisplayPort
- Masterizzatore Interno Blu-Ray LG BH10LS30 10x BR/DVD/CD Sata Bulk nero
- CPU Intel Core i5-2500K 3.30GHz Socket 1155 95W con GPU Sandy Bridge Boxed BX80623I52500K
- Alimentatore PC Corsair Enthusiast Series TX650 V2 650W 80Plus Bronze
- Scheda Madre Asrock H67DE3 Socket 1155 Intel H67 DDR3 SATA3 USB3 HDMI
- RAM DDR3 Geil Value Plus GVP36GB1333C7TC 1333MHz 6GB (3x2GB) CL7-7-7-
- ADATTATORE DA MINI DISPLAYPORT A HDMI, DVI E DISPLAYPORT
- 6 monitors Samsung SyncMaster 930BF
- 1 Supporto professionale per i 6 monitor

I have upgrade the Workstation adding 3 more monitors!
Look at https://vimeo.com/146922401

[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about hardware recommendation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing on that list of hardware should bring you problems running Ubuntu on.

Besides the rest of the hardware that should really not mater much, the graphics card is well supported in the latest nVidia drivers and the P67 chipset / Intel CPU are supported and should run without problems in any recent Linux distro.

Since the motherboard is running UEFI instead of a normal BIOS you probably will need to install the system with the alternate CD.

I am not sure how the support for UEFI motherboard's is in 11.10 but in 11.04 you needed a [few extra tricks](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFIBooting) to make your system boot normally.

Its a UEFI problem, not the chipset. If your not comfortable with that point look for a motherboard that runs a more standart BIOS.

Comment: What do you mean with: "Since the motherboard is running and UEFI BIOS you probably will need to install the system with the alternate CD.". Thanks

Comment: edited with more information.

Answer (score -1):

You can test compatibility before installing. Download the install image from ubuntu.com and burn it to a CD or USB (there are instructions on the download page).

The simply boot up from this CD or USB stick, and Ubuntu will run from it without touching your hard drive. You can check that everything seems to be working ok, and if you're satisfied click "install" to get the ball rolling.

Your Nvidia card will need proprietary drivers that you can't test when running from the live session, but will be available once you install. In the meantime your system will use a lower-specced open source driver called nouveau to drive the graphics card.

Comment: -1 It sounds like he wants to know if it works *before* he buys it.